# Why does Spark DataFrame run out of memory when same process on RDD completes fine?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a fairly large amount of data (a few TBs). When I use a subset of the data, I find that Spark dataframes are great to work with. However, when I try calculations on my full dataset the same code returns me a dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". What surprised me is that the process completes fine doing the same thing with an RDD. I thought dataframes were supposed to have better optimization. Is this a mistake in my approach or a limitation of dataframes?

For example, here is a simple task using dataframes that completes fine for a subset of my data and chokes on the full sample:

```
val records = sqlContext.read.avro(datafile)
val uniqueIDs = records.select("device_id").dropDuplicates(Array("device_id"))
val uniqueIDsCount = uniqueIDs.count().toDouble
val sampleIDs = uniqueIDs.sample(withReplacement = false, 100000/uniqueIDsCount)

sampleIDs.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "|").save(outputfile)
```

In this case it even chokes on the count.

However, when I try the same thing using RDDs in the following way it calculates fine (and pretty quickly at that).

```
val rawinput = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[Observation],NullWritable,
             AvroInputFormat[Observation]](rawinputfile).map(x=> x._1.datum)
val tfdistinct = rawinput.map(x => x.getDeviceId).distinct
val distinctCount = tfdistinct.count().toDouble
tfdistinct.sample(false, 100000/distinctCount.toDouble).saveAsTextFile(outputfile)
```

I'd love to keep using dataframes in the future, am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: I don't know the read.avro function, can you verify if the `records` dataframe is partitioned? I noticed that sometimes, when using the `sqlContext.read` function, the data comes in only one partition

Comment: @DanieldePaula I bet that you are on to something. Can I trouble you for a little help on how to figure out if a dataframe is partitioned? I was surprised that dataframe doesn't have a .partitions.size that I can check.
Assuming that you are right though, when you run into this with sqlContext.read do you just use .repartition? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe repartition could do the trick for posterior transformations. However, if you find a way to do the read operation parallelized, it would be better. To find the number of partitions, I think `df.rdd.partitions.length` should work. (for Spark 1.6: `df.rdd.getNumPartitions`)

Comment: No luck. For smaller samples `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` shows that my dataframe has many partitions (1 partition for each ~250 mb avro file, so thousands of partitions). When I try it on a dataframe of all of my data, the task runs out of memory and can't tell me how many partitions it is on.